# Problems while previewing image before upload on mobile browser, works fine on desktop browser

Tags: javascript, html

**Problem Definition:**
I want to select multiple images from mobile gallery and upload it. But before uploading, as soon as the user select images, I want to show preview of images selected. For achieving this, I am using the below code snippet which works perfectly on desktop browser. But, when the same is tried using mobile browser, it doesn't show the preview of images.
I tried by executing the below code as an html file as well as on the "try it yourself" editor which w3schools.com provide. In both cases, it works fine if I am doing it using a desktop browser but doesn't show preview of images if I am using mobile browser.
 W3shcools Editor: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro 
I am using below version of google chrome.
Desktop: 27.0.1453.94 m 
Mobile : 27.0.1453.90 
Mobile Model: Samsung Galaxy S2
Appreciate any help in this regard.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>File API - FileReader as Data URL</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>File API - FileReader</h1>
    </header>
    <article>
        <label for="files">Select multiple files: </label>
        <input id="files" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple/>
        <output id="result" />
    </article>
</body>

<script>
window.onload = function(){       
    //Check File API support
    if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
    {
        var filesInput = document.getElementById("files");

        filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){

            var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
            //console.log(files);
            var output = document.getElementById("result");
            //console.log(result);
            for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
            {
                var file = files[i];

                //Only pics will be allowed
                if(!file.type.match('image'))
                  continue;

                var picReader = new FileReader();

                picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){

                    var picFile = event.target;
                    console.log(event);
                    var div = document.createElement("div");

                    div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                            "title='" + picFile.name +"' width='80' height='80'/>";
                    console.log(div.innerHTML);                  
                    output.insertBefore(div,null);            

                });

                 //Read the image
                picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }                               

        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there an error message in the console? What happens if you step through it with a debugger?

Comment: I did not check the console. But instead of console.log(value), I tried alert(value). No alert is being shown on the device browser. On desktop browser, alert box got displayed with the value.

Comment: Where did you put the alert?

Comment: In above code, you see "//console.log(files), //console.log(result)". Those lines are replaced with alert(files), alert(result)

Comment: That means the event isn't firing. Is the event handler begin set? Put an alert before `filesInput.addEventListener(`. Oh, and replace the `console.log("Your browser does not support File API");` with an alert, too.

Comment: @RoToRa,
The control was not going inside  <code>picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){}</code>
Checked that by putting alert in every code block. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified another code snippet for it to work properly on browser. The code snippet, I modified is mentioned at the link below.
[Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded?rq=1)

Below is the code snippet which work properly on both desktop browser as well as mobile browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>File  API- FileReader as Data URL</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="myImage" src="#" alt="your image" />
</body>

<script>
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            document.getElementById('myImage').src=e.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
document.getElementById('imgInp').addEventListener("change",(function(e){
    readURL(this);
}));
</script>
</html>
```